# MATCH function with 2 columns lookup_array B:D

Tags: microsoft-excel

Any formula work as `=INDEX(A:B,MATCH(H6,B:C,0),1)`. My problem is `MATCH(H6,B:C,0)` only work for single column or row. below is just simple example. (names and dates can be more)

[image: Example]

Comment: What results do you expect? If A1 matches C3 then what should the formula return - what if there are multiple matches?

Comment: @barryhoudini there is only one match in the table.
[Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f7vF7.png)

Comment: @2ool What should happen for the last date? It's not in the cooking/date table at all.

Comment: @Jerry cell will be empty if no match.

Comment: @2ool Okay, how does the formula I provided suit you? I edited it so that it returns empty if there's no match.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks. your formula works well, but if i extend cooking/date names it return "-"

Comment: @2ool You have to adapt the ranges accordingly. I don't know how big or small your actual data is...

Comment: @Jerry my actual data is 70 names and 6 date columns. I didn't success in expanding the range. `=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$D$70,IFERROR(1/(1/SUMPRODUCT((Q16=$E$6:$J$70)*{1;2})),a)),"")`

Comment: @2ool Ah. That means you will have to change `{1;2}` to `ROW($E$6:$J$70)-5`. I would have used `ROW($B$4:$C$5)-3` with your example, but used `{1;2}` to make it shorter. The number to be removed is one row less than the first cell (`B4` -> -3, `E6` -> -5) if you see the pattern. This is to get the row of the first cell equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A generic type formula for this.....

`=IFERROR(INDEX($D$6:$D$70,SMALL(IF($E$6:$J$70=Q16,ROW($E$6:$J$70)-ROW($E$6)+1),1)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I know you said there was only one match but if there are more this will still "work" in that it will find the first match. It's also robust enough so that you can add rows above the data and it still functions

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$4:$A$5,IFERROR(1/(1/SUMPRODUCT((H4=$B$4:$C$5)*(ROW($B$4:$C$5)-3))),a)),"")
```

This will give you the name on the row with a matching date, and return "" (empty cell) if there are no matching dates (you didn't mention anything about what the formula should return if there is no matching date).